# How to get Gatling Reports in Teamcity

Tags: teamcity, karate

I am execuiting my karate-gatling reports from teamcity. I have my reports folder structure like below
target/gatling/xmltest-201506234/index.html
 The folder name with current timestamp, is there a way to use a wildcard and show it in reports tab for teamcity.

Or is there a way i can remove time stamp from the folder for gatling.

I have seen outPutDirectoryBaseName option for gatling but still it adds the timestamp to the basename

For cucumber reports I have path like this target/cucumber-html-reports/cucumber-feature.html
So in the reports configuration in teamcity i passed basepath as cucumber-html-reports/cucumber-feature.html and artifacts paths as target. So i am able to integrate reports with build.

Is there any way i can ahieve same for target/gatling/xmltest-201506234/index.html
I tried gatling/xml%/index.html its not working. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Can't say for karate-gatling, but FrontLine, Gatling's Enterprise version, does have a plugin for TeamCity.